# Modify XML file using Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I want to add a node in the last line of an existing XML file using Java. So I have followed the code below.

**Sample XML file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <mapping-configuration>
   <fields-mapping>
      <field compare="true" criteria="true" displayName="demo1"/>
      <field compare="true" criteria="true" displayName="demo2"/>
   </fields-mapping>
 </mapping-configuration>
```

**Code :**

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new File("C:/Desktop/test.xml"));  
    System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
    Node nList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getLastChild();
    System.out.println(nList.getNodeName());        
    Element newserver=doc.createElement("field");
    newserver.setAttribute("source", "33");
    nList.appendChild(newserver).normalize();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
    DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);          
    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:/Desktop/test.xml")); 
    transformer.transform(source, result);
```

So, I got the **result** as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <mapping-configuration>
     <fields-mapping>
        <field compare="true" criteria="true" displayName="demo1"/>
        <field compare="true" criteria="true" displayName="demo2">
        <field source="33"/>
        </field>  
     </fields-mapping>
 </mapping-configuration>
```

But my **expected Output** should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
 <mapping-configuration>
     <fields-mapping>
        <field compare="true" criteria="true" displayName="demo1"/>
        <field compare="true" criteria="true" displayName="demo2"/>
        <field source="33"/> 
     </fields-mapping>
 </mapping-configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
Node nList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes().item(0).getLastChild();
```

selects the last `field` element, and this:

```
 nList.appendChild(newserver);
```

adds your new element as a child of the last `field` element.

you want the new node as a child of the `fields-mapping` element, so try removing the unwanted `.getLastChild()`.